# @react-pdf/renderer Encountering "Unknown encoding: x-mac-roman" Error During Text Rendering

Tags: reactjs, fonts, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I'm encountering an issue with **@react-pdf/renderer** in one of my React projects. While it works perfectly fine in other projects, I'm getting an "Unknown encoding x-mac-roman" error in this particular project.

### Error Details:

The error occurs in the **encodingWidth** method (line 106) of the **String.js** file.
I suspect this file is used by @react-pdf/renderer for text rendering.

[image]

### Font Registration:

Here's how I'm registering the font:

```js
Font.register({
  family: 'MyFontFamily',
  src: 'http://my-cdn-path/MyFontFamily.ttf',
  format: 'truetype'
})
```

### Font Usage:

And this is how I'm including the font family in styles:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  label: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'red',
    fontFamily: 'MyFontFamily'
  }
})
```

### Question:

Has anyone else encountered this issue with **@react-pdf/renderer**? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

### Furthermore

It looks like is an issue with the font I'm using (Gilmer), I try with a random one and works.

Comment: A font contains a character-to-glyph ('cmap') table that can support one or more character encodings. Most recent fonts use Unicode encoding, but some fonts can support only legacy Mac encodings, one of those being "Mac Roman". So, it's possible that your font has a cmap with only the legacy Mac Roman encoding and react-pdf doesn't support that.